# Data flow optimisation using HOOPL

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, hoopl

I am Haskell programmer ( I generally implement [algorithms in Haskell](http://mukeshiiitm.wordpress.com) )  and trying to understand [HOOPL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hoopl) library but I am not able to decode it. I don't have  compiler background ( currently learning from Coursera and Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools ) and  It would be great if you can suggest me a systematic way to proceed  for understanding HOOPL library ( what is the prerequisite ).  Lets say I have a small Haskell code on which I want to apply  data flow optimization using HOOPL

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add x y = z where
   x' = 1
   y' = 1 -- this will be dead code elimination 
   z = x' + 1
```

How to write  HOOPL code to optimise this. It would be great if you can give  a bit better example and pardon me if I sound stupid.

Comment: you don't sound stupid. [This paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/c--/dfopt-popl10.pdf) looks quite readable and appears to address dead-code elimination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good place to start is pulling the git repo, which has lots of additional files compared to what's on Hackage. Lookin the /testing subdirectory, and you can see some simple code defining a basic imperative language and some optimizations on it.